# How to Cast Reincarnate On Yourself After You Have Died?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am wondering how a single-classed druid would go about casting Reincarnate on herself after she has died (if such is even possible)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Check this out.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency) Have a magic item forged that casts this spell on you when you use it. That should just about cover everything you need.

Have a wizard forge a magical item for you. He'll cast *Contingency* and you'll cast *Reincarnate.* From there, it's just a standard Craft check.

EDIT: There is one tiny thing I overlooked. In Pathfinder, *Contingency* can only be cast once until the conditions are met, and the *Contingency* is expended. Depends on your DM, but if he likes, he could reasonably enforce that the wizard can't cast *Contingency* again until the item is used or destroyed. Something to think about.

EDIT 2: @Molot has provided a fairly simple solution to the *Contingency* issue.

> Buy a scroll and UMD it, or ask a wizard who does not have contingency among his spells known to cast it for you. Or skip the wizzie altogether and let Druid create that item, "access through another magic item" is vague, there is no restriction that says there must be someone able to actually use source item directly.

I don't think it would work as easy as Molot says, since the spell restriction itself says:

> You can use only one contingency spell at a time; if a second is cast, the first one (if still active) is dispelled.

This means that using the scroll would still impose the *Contingency* restriction on the  caster, even if they aren't even a wizard and are UMD'ing it, as far as I can tell. Still, if you can find someone else willing to do it for you, you're good, or even if the Druid can make the item himself like he also suggested.

Although, this all kind of hinges on how your DM interprets "dispels" in this context. If they think that the magic is tied to the item completely, then so be it, it stays once the wizard casts *Contingency* elsewhere. But it seems like it would also be reasonable for him to say that the ring loses its effect if the caster uses *Contingency* elsewhere, or perhaps until the other *Contingency* is resolved. I don't really know how I'd handle it personally as a DM.

Comment: @DavidWilkins ["although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed"](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html)

Comment: What else do I need to say? If you don't understand how magic item creation works, you can ask that in a different question. In summary: a wizard or sorcerer has a plain, gold ring. He offers his druid party member to forge him a ring of contingent reincarnate. The druid accepts. The wizard makes his craft checks as per usual, then at some point during the creation of the item, the druid casts Reincarnate. The wizard harnesses his comrade's magic and puts it in the ring. It's quite a simple process; I've done it before to make a shadowed chain shirt as well, since wizards cannot cast Silence.

Comment: "Contingency can only be cast once" - there is an easy workaround. Buy a scroll and UMD it, or ask a wizard who does not have contingency among his spells known to cast it for you. Or skip the wizzie altogether and let Druid create that item, "access through another magic item" is vague, there is no restriction that says there must be someone able to actually use source item directly.

Answer (score 6):

There's the [reincarnated druid archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/reincarnated-druid) that does this as a class feature once you get past a Lvl 5.

1. Level 5 druid dies, for comedic effect right after leveling to 5.
2. Druid reincarnates in a new, young adult body of a race off table, about 1 mile from the original with negative levels.
3. If the new body dies within 1 week, then they are killed off effectively, as the Many Lives feature has a 1 week cooldown.